# Filling circular segment using Tkz-Euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tkz-euclide

I tried to fill a circular segment but I'm having trouble doing it. Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/C, 4/0/B}
\tkzDrawTriangle[pythagore](C,B)
\tkzGetPoint{A}
\tkzDefCircle[circum](A,B,C)
\tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzGetLength{cr}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\cr pt)
\tkzDrawPoints(O)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](O)
\tkzLabelSegment[above left](A,B){\Large 6 cm}
\tkzLabelSegment[above right](B,C){\Large 8 cm}
\begin{scope}[fill=gray, opacity=0.5]
\fill[clip] (B) -- (A) arc (90:-90:1.5cm) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'll rotate the picture by 143 degrees.

Comment: I added `\usetkzobj{all}` to make your code compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Really easy with the `calc` library. Perhaps even easier with `tkz-euclide` *if* you speak French, which I don't.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/C, 4/0/B}
\tkzDrawTriangle[pythagore](C,B)
\tkzGetPoint{A}
\tkzDefCircle[circum](A,B,C)
\tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzGetLength{cr}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\cr pt)
\tkzDrawPoints(O)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](O)
\tkzLabelSegment[above left](A,B){\Large 6 cm}
\tkzLabelSegment[above right](B,C){\Large 8 cm}
\begin{scope}[fill=gray, opacity=0.5]
\fill let \p1=($(A)-(O)$),\p2=($(B)-(O)$),
\n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={atan2(\y2,\x2)},\n3={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in 
(B) -- (A) arc (\n1:\n2:\n3) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Explanation**: `\p1=($(A)-(O)$)` means that the coordinates of `\p1`, `\x1` and `\y1` will be the x- and y-coordinates of the vector `O-A`, likewise for `\p2` and `B`. Correspondingly, `\n1` and `\n2` will be the angles of `A` and `B`, respectively, and `\n3` the radius of the circle. These are the quantities needed to draw the arc.

Comment: P.S. You can rotate the picture, of course, by saying `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=143]`. You can even compute the *exact* rotation angle by saying `\path let \p1=($(A)-(O)$),\n1={180-atan2(\y1,\x1)} in \pgfextra{\typeout{\n1}};`, after which you may decide to use `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=143.13011]`. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Also available in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html); here wrapped up in `luamplib`, so please compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

[I hope that I have correctly interpreted the OP "rotate the picture by 143 degrees".]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path o; 
    o = fullcircle scaled 10 cm;

    % "time" around the circle, 360° = 8 points
    numeric a, b, c;
    c = 0;                 % = 0°
    b = 2/45 angle (3,4);  % = 106.26°
    a = 4;                 % = 180°

    pair A, B, C;
    C = point c of o;
    B = point b of o;
    A = point a of o;

    fill subpath (b,a) of o -- cycle withcolor 3/4 white;

    draw o;
    draw A--B--C--cycle;

    dotlabel.lft("$A$", A);
    dotlabel.top("$B$", B);
    dotlabel.rt ("$C$", C);
    dotlabel.bot("$O$", origin);

    label.lrt (decimal round(abs(A-B)/cm) & "\thinspace cm", 1/2[A,B]);
    label.llft(decimal round(abs(B-C)/cm) & "\thinspace cm", 1/2[B,C]);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simply a calculation error of half the angle AOB which measures arcsin(3/5) or about 36.8699 degrees with a radius of 2.5 cm.

This give:

```
\fill[clip] (B) -- (A) arc (36.8699:-36.8699:2.5cm) -- cycle;
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/C, 4/0/B}
\tkzDrawTriangle[pythagore](C,B)
\tkzGetPoint{A}
\tkzDefCircle[circum](A,B,C)
\tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzGetLength{cr}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\cr pt)
\tkzDrawPoints(O)
\tkzLabelPoints[left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[right](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](O)
\tkzLabelSegment[above left](A,B){\Large 6 cm}
\tkzLabelSegment[above right](B,C){\Large 8 cm}
\draw[fill=gray!50] (B) -- (A) arc (asin(3/5:-asin(3/5):2.5cm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: fill-rect-trian]

Comment: @marmot Yes, indeed, we can make these calculations by `pgf`. I never use and certainly mistakenly the computing capabilities of `pgf`.. You are right `clip` is useless, on the other hand it is necessary to make `draw` because otherwise the segment is not plotted. I edited my answers. I upvoted some time ago too on your answer :)

Comment: @marmot, I noticed that for some time now, you've been deleting your comments. It is not a good idea, reading the comments from the beginning often helps to understand the evolution of an answer. Moreover, this makes the other comments incomprehensible. :(